# stopwatch not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just starting with javascript, I've been trying to make a simple stopwatch, I found a couple of ways to do it , then I came across this function ... the code doesn't work as a stopwatch unless we return a function , can somebody help me understand why????

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
   var tick = function(i) {
       return ()=>{console.log(i);}
   };
   setTimeout(tick(i), 500 * i);
}
```

Comment: What do you want. What is problem in this code? Do you want a simpler solution? or need any kind of explanation?

Comment: I want to know how the setInterval() works , and why does it break when i click it multiple times, i've tried the boolean varibles to disable the start button ones clicked, but when i add the restart and stop button , the same problem happens again ( the timer speeds up)         Note: i've read that my problem is caused because the setinterval's function gets called on top of the one before it , wich makes it look like it's speeding ... but am still having problem understanding my code :( ....  I think this is the simplest solution, yet am still struggling to understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `setInterval` and  `clearInterval` for your case.

```
var i = 10;
    var tick = function(i) {
                return ()=>{
                    console.log(i--);
                    if(i == 0) clearInterval(timer);
                }
       };
    var timer = setInterval(tick(i), 500);
```

If you want to have stopwatch, you can `clearInterval` in stop button click event

```
function stop(){
    clearInterval(timer);
}
```

Update:

I combined Start and Stop in only one button using `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`

```js
var i = 1;
var timer;
var tick = function(i) {
            return ()=>{
                console.clear();
                console.log(i++);
                
                //if(i == 0) clearInterval(timer);
            }
   };
function start(){
    document.getElementById("start").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("stop").disabled = false;
    timer = setInterval(tick(i), 500);
    
}
function stop(){
    clearInterval(timer);
    document.getElementById("stop").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("start").disabled = false;
}


(function() {
  document.getElementById("start2").addEventListener("click", start2);
})();

function start2(){
    
    timer = setInterval(tick(i), 500);
 document.getElementById("start2").innerHTML = "Stop";
 document.getElementById("start2").removeEventListener("click", start2);
 document.getElementById("start2").addEventListener("click", stop2);
    
}
function stop2(){
    clearInterval(timer);
    document.getElementById("start2").innerHTML = "Start";
 document.getElementById("start2").removeEventListener("click", stop2);
 document.getElementById("start2").addEventListener("click", start2);
}
```

```html
<button id="start" onclick="start()">Start</button>
<button  id="stop" onclick="stop()">Stop</button>

<h2>Combine Start and Stop</h2>
<button id="start2" >Start</button>
```

Comment: <button id="start">start</button>

Comment: should make the button start/stop and the second one reset. This way if someone wants to press the button multiple times is will only start or stop. You will need to keep track of the active state of the button. i.e. if it is on start or stop. (note: stop will need to be programmed to continue from the number it stopped on when the users presses start again)

Comment: @HienNguyen Disabling the buttons or using the same button for both start and stop doesn't solve the problem. What if someone don't want to disable.

Comment: Maheer Ali, I combined them to only button

Answer (score 0):

```
below code will help you

<h1><time>00:00:00</time></h1>
<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
<button id="clear">clear</button>
</pre>   

<script>
            var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
            start = document.getElementById('start'),
            stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
            clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
            seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
            t;

        function add() {
            seconds++;
            if (seconds >= 60) {
                seconds = 0;
                minutes++;
                if (minutes >= 60) {
                    minutes = 0;
                    hours++;
                }
            }

            h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

            timer();
        }
        function timer() {
            t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
        }



       start.onclick = function(){
       timer();
       start.disabled=true;
       }

       /* Stop button */
       stop.onclick = function() {
       clearTimeout(t);
       start.disabled=false;
       }

        /* Clear button */
        clear.onclick = function() {
            h1.textContent = "00:00:00";
            seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0;
        }

        </script>
```

Comment: hello, i've tried your code, and it has the same problem as mine, if you click the start button multiple times, the stopwatch speeds up and the stop button wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Because [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) first parameter has to be a function.
Your code works because it immediately executes the `tick(i)` function, which returns a function and that one is used 500ms later as callback.